# NSTimer in Cocoa (MAC) app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstimer, nsthread

I am working on a timer application where i have used 5-6 timers running at one time, I need all the timers running at the same time. For ex. calculating a time, updating the UI etc.

But this is hangs my app, After some time, its started not responding.

Then i quit the app and re-launch but this time i didn't start the timer (Only one timer is running) and i found that application is fine this time.

I think the issue is due to usage of multiple timers at the same time as these timers are updating the UI frequently after every seconds. I need to updated my label with the updated time, but how i could do this without using an NSTimer. If NSThread is an option then please give me an example to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple NSTimers slows down the Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907514/multiple-nstimers-slows-down-the-application)

Comment: @ParagBafna Do you have any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: @york I think you'll need to post some code showing how you create and start the timers.

Comment: Get a stacktrace.  At least using lldb, or perhaps even better using the Time Profiler in Instruments.  Given that you'll be able to see what it's doing that's hanging your app, in particular your main runloop.  Otherwise it's all just speculation and wild guesses.